# Analyticity of eigenvalues and eigenvectors in the presence of a gap?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose I have a Hermitian/self-adjoint $N \times N$ matrix $H$ with matrix elements $\{h_{ij}\}$, such that $H$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ which is $\Delta$ away from any other eigenvalue in the spectrum.

Is it true that if we change $h_{ij}$, then $\lambda$ must vary analytically as a function of $h_{ij}$, assuming the eigenvalue remains at least $\Delta$ away from any other eigenvalues?
Furthermore, do the elements of the associated eigenvector vary analytically with $h_{ij}$?

Initially I thought that both of these statements are trivially true, however, I can only find statements saying that the eigenvalues are continuous in the matrix elements (using the characteristic polynomial), which has left me sceptical that it is true. One could also do a perturbative expansion (as if often done in physics), however, this only seems to be true asymptotically.

It seems like the problem with analyticity occurs when there is a crossing of eigenvalues, but if one ensures a gap around a given eigenvalue, can one prove anything stronger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching online you will find many proofs that every simple  root depends *continuously* on the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial . However, your question asks if the root is *analytic* in those coefficients. It is apparently surprisingly difficult to track down an elementary proof of that result online.

**Caveat.** I will interpret your statement that "*there is a root that is $\Delta$ away from the other roots* " to mean that your root is a **simple root** (not a repeated root) of the characteristic polynomial $p(x)$. At a multiple root the argument below is invalid and a far more complicated discussion is required.
Since the root $r_0$ is simple, one can show that $p'( x)$ does not vanish when $x=r_0$.

Consider what happens when we vary the coefficients of the polynomial.
Let $C=(c_0, c_1 , \ldots, c_n)$ be the list of coefficients of the polynomial $p(x;C)$ whose roots we wish to analyze. Let $C_0$ be the current list of such coefficients for the polynomial.  Because $p(x, C_0)$  has an **simple root**  located $x= r_0$, as noted above, the derivative $\frac{\partial p(x,C)}{ \partial x}|_{(x=r_0, C= C_0)} \ne 0$. This is exactly the condition that allows one to invoke the **analytic local implicit function theorem** to conclude that
the  equation $0= p(x,C)$ has a unique local solution $x(C)$   that agrees with $r_0$ when $C= C_0$. The solution is an analytic  function of the variables $C$, valid  throughout some  possibly small region about $C_0$ in coefficient space.

One good reference  text is *The Implicit Function Theorem*, by Krantz and Parks. The last part of the book discusses the analytic version of the Implicit Function Theorem.

Comment: Thank you for this! I suspected this was the case, but the lack of proof online lead to me to think that maybe there was a caveat I didn't understand (e.g. if there was a multiplicity in the other eigenvalues which caused this to fail)!

Comment: Also, the simple eigenvector is also analytic, since it can be found explicitly just by solving a system of equations that have $\lambda$ in them. BTW I saw references online to extra strong statements regarding GLOBAL continuity of Hermitian matrix eigenvalues, but AFAIK  the analyticity might fail when eigenvalues cross.

Comment: Interesting, I'll search and see if I can find a reference for global continuity too! Thanks again!